# How to Auto Click in HTML Button

Tags: javascript, html, automation, click

```
<h1>Welcome to My Page!</h1>
<h2>My name is Bob.</h2>
<h3>I hope you like it here.</h3>
<embed src="MY WEBSITE LINK" style="width:500px; height: 300px;">
<input type="checkbox" id="btd" onmouseover="myFunction()" onclick="alert('clicked')">

<script>
jQuery(function(){
   jQuery('#btd').click();
});
</script>
```

I have the code. But didn't Work.
http://www.imagebam.com/image/31ac1b820717083

How to Auto Click Button Continue, from Image?

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking. Your HTML code does not contain a button. It is unclear how this relates to the code shown in the image.

Comment: http://www.imagebam.com/image/31ac1b820717083

Answer (score 4):

We can't do auto click in HTML, but we can call any function that the button does with Jquery.
To work Jquery code, you want to add this to your code

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Actually when we click any button, it calls a function, that may be our own function or built in one.
Here Javascript can easily call any function without any button
**Like this**

```js
//define the function

function alertsomething(){
  alert("Hey, This is an alert inside that function");
}

//function works when button clicks 
$("#btd").click(function(){
  alertsomething();
})

//function automatically when page loads
$(document).ready(function(){
  alertsomething();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btd" >Click me</button>
```

Here are the two ways to call a function. One is when you click the button and another one is when your page loads, that function will call automatically...

Thanks

Comment: Image 1: http://www.imagebam.com/image/2236d9820783993                         Image 2: http://www.imagebam.com/image/f1bbfc820784033                      Not Work :( any suggestion plzz

Comment: Any idea if this does not work how can I automatically click randomly on location?

Comment: Where i'm wrong my friend, https://openload.co/f/tqNMGSLldao/2018_04_14_15_31_53_1364x768.avi.mp4

Comment: You must remember that, In javascript if we click any button, it is calling a function or some line of statement that include what they want to after click. So, Here we calling that functions or statements without clicking on  it. That's how we can automate click. Remember you can only do it in your own website, and you can't click on specific place  with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script> setInterval(function(){  document.getElementById('btn').click() }, 10000); </script>
```

Its working script for me
Send "data" from FORM 'POST' to refresh HTML page whith PHP code